# How to reference an AWS resource created via SAM in a Lambda?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I am trying to write to an SQS Queue that I create in the same SAM template as my lambda. To send a message to the queue I need the URL.

`client.send_message(QueueUrl='string', MessageBody='string', ...)`

I can get the URL if I have the name of the queue (`client.get_queue_url(QueueName='string', QueueOwnerAWSAccountId='string')`), but this is randomly generated when deployed by SAM. For a Function you can specify FunctionName in the template.yaml, but I haven't found an example of this for a Queue.

I know that in the template.yaml I can use `!Ref MyQueue` but I don't know of an equivalent to use in the lambda. I assume there is a trick, I just don't know that trick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in the queue URL as an environment variable to the lambda. That allows you use the `!Ref MyQueue` in the template to reference the queue. Just add that to the `Environment` -> `Variables` section of the lambda configuration.

Comment: Got this working, thanks. The only downside I see here is local testing. I assume I need to use local stack to accomplish that?